# How To View Recently Installed Plugins in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

One month ago , my site was so fast but now after installing list of plugins my site loading so slow, Is there any way to displaying my recent installed plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file=the plugin you want to know it's creation date 
date --date=$(stat -c%y $file | cut -c1-10) +"%d %b"

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a way that I'm aware of in the WordPress admin. The date a plugin is installed isn't stored however you could simply look at the datestamps in your plugin directory.

Open up your site in your preferred FTP client, FileZilla for example, and navigate to your plugin directory. e.g. /wp-content/plugins/

Order the list of plugins by their Last Modified date.

Comment: very good note:Last Modified date but when am checking them they displaying also my editing .. Is there any way to view created at?

Answer (score 0):

There is aplugin which shows the install date, activated, deactivates and plugin last updated date and they have also provide option where user can decide which information they want to see.

Knowing plugin install date help us to debug any problem created by plugin, i.e. if I know the date after which I installed multiple plugin and suddenly I started facing problem then knowing install date will be a big plus point.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/xgen-date-information/

Hope this was helpful.